# Авторизация пользователя на сайте MVC с шаблоном Microsoft

Tags: c#, mvc

Как сделать авторизацию, когда создаешь проект с шаблоном MVC галкой individual user accaunt? Где мне указать коннект к базе и непосредственно функцию добавления пользователя?

Answer (score 1):

Стандартный шаблон MVC + Individual User Accounts использует строку соединения с именем DefaultConnection из web.config:

```xml
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication3-20160210010241.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication3-20160210010241;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Имя строки соединения задается в Models\IdentityModel.cs:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Код для создания пользователя лежит в Controllers\AccountController.cs:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

Answer (score -1):

Всё, я разобрался.
http://johnatten.com/2013/10/27/configuring-db-connection-and-code-first-migration-for-identity-accounts-in-asp-net-mvc-5-and-visual-studio-2013/
В статье все хорошо расписано. И там же есть еще пара полезных статей по этому поводу.

Всем спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.